# addthis.com facebook share to wall - changing title text link using open graph protocol not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, addthis

Is there a way to change what the title text points to once it becomes a link on the facebook wall/message?

I'm using the bookmark.php link mentioned here: http://www.addthis.com/help/custom-buttons.

I set these meta tags, thinking "og:url" would set the title text link, but instead it only set the text that is between the title and description:
og:title
og:description
og:image
og:url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question: When using the share button (via FB.Share), you cannot override the from url unless you also are scraping the og (open graph protocol) meta values from that same page.

It might still be possible to override the values by using facebook connect and creating a Facebook application instead of just FB.Share. I'm not sure.